# Text is not flowing around a float in IE7 as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with floats in IE7 which I just can't figure out. I div containing a list to float to the right so that the text stays to the left. The method I have used works in other browsers, but not IE7. I have simplified the code to make the issue clearer:

```
<div class="contentarea">
    <div class="rightmenu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="item-472"><a href="/joomla/index.php/novazeal-websites" >Website Building</a></li>
            <li class="item-473"><a href="/joomla/index.php/novazeal-joomla-training" >Joomla Training</a></li>
        </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="item-page">
        <p>This is the services page. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy yellow dog. My dog has fleas, The fox may catch them. I wouldn't want to be that fox.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevent CSS:

```
.contentarea {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 794px;
    min-height:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    overflow:visible;
    position:relative; 
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}


.rightmenu {

    float:right;

}
```

I am guess that there is a property coming in from even higher up the hierarchy which is preventing floats from working properly in IE7, but I have tried changing everything I can think of without success. Any thoughts wold be much appreciated.

Terry Rozmus.

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML containing the recalcitrant text? I assume the p tag you've posted is not the content you're referring to…

Comment: I figured it out myself. I added: 

.item-page {
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

The class item-page is added by Joomla, but I forgot that it is actually between contentarea and the p tags in the hierarchy so I didn't pay any attention to how it was affecting the layout.

Comment: Comment probably ate your HTML. Post it as an answer!

Comment: I can't answer my own questions on stackoverflow because my experience level isn't high enough, but I finished the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Use float: right for both divs. The use of both float left and right for two or more rather equally big divs inside one div might cause the trouble you are experiencing in IE7.

Comment: I tried that. It had the same effect: the text div was pushed below the side div in the same way as it was when I had the text set on float:left. I have made a separate for style sheet for IE7 and earlier because the solution (adding style declarations in the middle .item-page div) actually caused the same problem to occur in other browsers.